# Can polarizing film reflect light instead of blocking light?

Tags: light, liquid-crystals

I was thinking about how to electorally switch glass between transparent and reflective just out of curiosity. I thought that maybe you could polarize the reflective glass in the vertical direction and polarize the light hitting the glass in the vertical direction as well, then have a layer of liquid crystals selectively reorient the light into the horizontal direction which will cause the light to be reflected back. Is this possible?

Comment: Should be the arrangement of a LCD? Except for the back light replaced by a mirror? It fits better to Physics SE, tough a better answer than my comment is certainly possible here.

Comment: Basically except I would need it to also let light through like a window when off so I couldn’t just a mirror behind it.

Comment: it should be possible as well. Otherwise active windows do exist.